# Multiple Eureka servers configuration doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm using spring cloud Hoxton.SR10 and spring boot 2.3.8.RELEASE

**Problem:**
Comma-separated eureka client bootstrap configuration doesn't work properly. When client starts it checks only first eureka url from the defaultZone list (peer1) and if its down doesn't attempt to contact peer2. Same configuration worked ok in Hoxton.SR4.

Client bootstrap config:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        serviceId: config-server
      failFast: true
      retry:
        max-interval: 5000
        max-attempts: 200
  application:
    name: eureka-test
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl: ##service-url behaves the same
      defaultZone: https://peer1:7777/eureka/,https://peer2:7777/eureka/
```

Issue appears to be in:

```
org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.config.EurekaConfigServerBootstrapConfiguration
    private static String getEurekaUrl(EurekaClientConfigBean config, Environment env) {
        List<String> urls = EndpointUtils.getDiscoveryServiceUrls(config, "defaultZone", new EurekaConfigServerBootstrapConfiguration.HostnameBasedUrlRandomizer(env.getProperty("eureka.instance.hostname")));
        return (String)urls.get(0);
    }
```

this method explicitly takes only first peer from defaultZone list and creates a client using it, whereas in Hoxton.SR4 RetryableEurekaHttpClinet was created via EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.

I didn't find any reported bug for this issue in spring-cloud tracker and wondering if I missed something, is there a dependency or configuration piece that will switch on the retryable client? Maybe any known workaround?
Downgrade or upgrade to working version of spring cloud will require changing spring-boot version as well which is a pain in big project.

P.S.
Same issue exists in last Hoxton version SR12 and appears to be present in 2020.0.1 as well (although didn't try this one).

Thanks

Comment: Neither `Hoxton` nor `2020.0.x` are supported any more. Can you reproduce the issue in either the newest `2021.0.x` or the newest `2022.0.x`?

Comment: Tried 2021.0.8 it has same problem, classes were moved around but logic remained the same, first url from deafultZone list is used to construct client: org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.config.HostnameBasedUrlRandomizer#getEurekaUrl. Correctly fetches list from config file but then there's a line: return (String)urls.get(0);